# Initializing a program using a Singleton

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I have read multiple articles about why singletons are bad.
I know it has few uses like logging but what about initalizing and deinitializing.
Are there any problems doing that?
I have a scripting engine that I need to bind on startup to a library.
Libraries don't have main() so what should I use?
Regular functions or a Singleton.
Can this object be copied somehow:

```
class
{
public:
   static void initialize();
   static void deinitialize();

}  bootstrap;
```

If not why do people hide the copy ctor, assignment operator and the ctor?

Comment: Did you ask something like "How do I define a set of "almost" global variables limited in scope and force the initializer function to always be executed before the actual use of such data-set?" ?

Comment: No variables needed.
Only excecuting functions that bind the library to the scripting engine.

Comment: Yes, the object can be copied, but nothing happens if you do so. And people hide copy ctor and assignment operator to prevent it from being copied. And what do you mean, "no variables needed"? You want to perform a binding, and that binding has to be stored as state somewhere which the functions can operate on.

Comment: Is there any possibility you might want to have two instances of the scripting language, for instance one is a fully featured interp with access to the filesystem and the second is for running untrusted code and has reduced functionality.  Could you do this with a singleton?

Comment: @jalf: The variables are stored inside the scripting engine.
I don't handle them at all.
I just need to call the functions that bind my classes to the script.
Can you show me how can it be copied?
@TokenMacGuy: The answer is no for both.

Comment: @the_drow: If nothing else, you need to store a pointer to the scripting engine, don't you? If not, then the scripting engine is already pretty much a singleton, and you don't really have much choice. Only one instance of it can exist, because the designers of the scripting engine imposed that (unnecessary and inelegant) limitation. If that is the case, most of the arguments against singletons are moot, not because they don't matter, but because you're going to suffer the disadvantages *anyway*.

Comment: a simple way to do a singleton is to have a function like this

yourobject& getInstance()
{
  static yourobject obj;
  return obj;
}

all caveats still apply mentioned by jalf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libraries in C++ have a much simpler way to perform initialization and cleanup. It's the exact same way you'd do it for anything else. RAII.

Wrap everything that needs to be initialized in a class, and perform its initialization in the constructor. Voila, problems solved.

All the usual problems with singletons still apply:

- You *are* going to need more than one instance, even if you hadn't planned for it. If nothing else, you'll want it when unit-testing. Each test should initialize the library from scratch so that it runs in a clean environment. That's hard to do with a singleton approach.
- You're screwed as soon as these singletons start referencing each others. Because the actual initialization order isn't visible, you quickly end up with a bunch of circular references resulting in accessing uninitialized singletons or stack overflows or deadlocks or other fun errors *which could have been caught at compile-time if you hadn't been obsessed with making everything global*.
- Multithreading. It's usually a bad idea to force all threads to share the same instance of a class, becaus it forces that class to lock and synchronize **everything**, which costs a lot of performance, and may lead to deadlocks.
- Spaghetti code. You're hiding your code's dependencies every time you use a singleton or a global. It is no longer clear which objects a function depends on, because not all of them are visible as parameters. And because you don't need to add them as parameters, you easily end up adding far more dependencies than necessary. Which is why singletons are almost impossible to remove once you have them.

Comment: Good idea. I'm not sure that I can do RAII.
The reason is that I need all the resources loaded at once even if I don't use them.

Comment: So? Have the user create a master object reprsenting the entire library. That object loads all resources when it is constructed, whether or not they're used. All library functions operate on that object, and when that object goes out of scope, the entire library is unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

A singleton's purpose is to have only ONE instance of a certain class in your system.
The C'tor, D'tor and CC'tor are hidden, in order to have a single access point for receiving the only existing instance.

Usually the instance is static (could be allocated on the heap too) and private, and there's a static method (usually called GetInstance) which returns a reference to this instance.

The question you should ask yourself when deciding whether to have a singleton is : Do I really need to enforce having one object of this class?

There's also the inheritance problem - it can make things complicated if you are planning to inherit from a singleton.

Another problem is [How to kill a singleton](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/to_kill_a_singleton) (the web is filled with articles about this issue)

In some cases it's better to have your private data held statically rather than having a singleton, all depends on the domain.

Note though, that if you're multi-threaded, static variables can give you a pain in the XXX...

So you should analyse your problem carefully before deciding on the design pattern you're going to use...

In your case, I don't think you need a singleton because you want the libraries to be initialized at the beginning, but it has nothing to do with enforcing having only one instance of your class. You could just hold a static flag (static bool Initialized)  if all you want is to ensure initializing it only once.

Calling a method once is not reason enough to have a singleton.

Comment: The code you provided is not a singleton because it's not enough to declare two methods as static. You have to have your instance created within a static method (hidden as private of course) and have this static method return this instance. you also need to put your C'tor, CC'tor and D'tor as private to prevent users from creating multiple instances or deleting instances. Please check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern for details

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to provide an interface for your libraries so that multiple modules (or threads) can use them simultaneously. If you really need to run some code when modules are loaded then use singletons to init *parts* that **must** be init once.

Answer (score 0):

count the number of singletons in your design, and call this number 's'

count the number of threads in your design, and call this number 't'

now, raise t to the s-th power; this is roughly the number of hairs you are likely to lose while debugging the resulting code.

(I personally have run afoul of code that has over 50 singletons with 10 different threads all racing to get to .getInstance() first)